# Salesforce API access using OAUTH2.0 working for some site but not working for others

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I'm using salesforce free trial version which doesn't have API access enabled by default. I tried using oauth 2.0 to access the API using access_token and it gave this error `API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG`. Now, when I tried the same thing on a different app which uses OAUTH2.0 to get the data, the API worked properly. While another app showed that the API is not enabled. I wanted to know how this app was able to access my data and other apps were not able to access it ? Is there any workaround to this ?

The app that was able to access my data was `dooly.ai` and I also tried using `scratchpad` which showed that API is not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain apps that have gone through a [Security Review](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_overview.htm) can have elevated permissions that allow them to work in orgs that do not have API access. In SOAP, this is a Client Id that is passed in by a special header. For the REST APIs, the Client Id for the Connected App is granted permission to use the API. Not all APIs are supported by this mechanism.

This special feature granted to ISVs are why some apps are able to work, and others are not. ISV apps are published by Salesforce Partners, and have proven that their apps are secure, and in turn, salesforce.com has granted them additional permissions to reach a wider subscriber base.

You can read more about this feature in this [Developer Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/05/integrating-salesforce-primer-isvs).